# Angular - How to exclude image from the insert when image is null

Tags: angular

In Angular-12, I am triying to upload image and also insert other fields. The image will go into a directly in the backend, which the name will be inserted in the database. I have this code:

Interface:

```
export interface IVehicle {
  id?: number;
  registration_number: string;
  vehicle_image?: any;
}
```

Service:

```
public addVehicle(vehicle: IVehicle): Observable<IVehicle> {
  return this.http.post<IVehicle>(this.api.baseURL + 'vehicles/add', vehicle, this.httpOptions);
}
```

Component:

```js
createForm!: FormGroup;
vehicle!: IVehicle;
isLoading = false;
isSubmitted = false;
url = '';
path = "";
files ? : any;
data1: any;

constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
  private router: Router,
  private store: Store < AppState > ,
  private vehicleService: VehicleService,
) {}

createVehicle() {
  this.createForm = this.fb.group({
      registration_number: ['', [Validators.required]],
      [
        RxwebValidators.extension({
          extensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "png", "gif", "svg"]
        })
      ]]
  });
}

onSelectFile(event: any) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url
    this.files = event.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = (event: any) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
      //   console.log(event);
      this.url = event.target.result;
    }
  }
}

submitForm() {
  this.isSubmitted = true;

  // stop here if form is invalid
  if (this.createForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }
  this.vehicle = {
    registration_number: this.createForm.value.registration_number,
    vehicle_image: (this.files, this.files.name),
  };

  this.vehicleService.addVehicle(this.vehicle).subscribe(res => {
      this.data1 = res;
      this.tokenCreateHandler(res);
    },
    error => {
      this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
}
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="registration_number">Registration No.:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="registration_number" placeholder="XB-547-AG" class="form-control" required/>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="isSubmitted || (fc.registration_number.touched && fc.registration_number.invalid)">
    <div *ngIf="fc.registration_number.hasError('required')">
      <div class="text-danger">
        Registration Number is required!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="vehicle_image">Vehicle Image:</label>
    <div class="card-body box-profile">
      <div class="text-center">
        <img class="profile-user-img img-fluid img-circle" [src]="url || 'assets/img/no-image.png'" alt="No Vehicle Image" onerror="this.src='assets/img/no-image.png'" style="height:150px; width:150px">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input formControlName="vehicle_image" id="vehicle_image" type="file" class="form-control" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.bmp,.png,.gif,.svg" (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
        <div *ngIf="fc.vehicle_image.touched && fc.vehicle_image.invalid">
          <div *ngIf="fc.vehicle_image.hasError('extension')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Enter valid File Type!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The vehicle_image should be nullable.

How do I add a condition that when no vehicle_image is selected, it should bypass and there should be no error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, maybe? You can check if uploaded file's length is greater than 0. If it is 0 then the uploaded file is null or does not contain any information. In this case, your upload method returns and nothing happens.

```
onSelectFile(event: any) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    let img = event.target.files[0];
    
    // Check if img is something valid
    if(img.length == 0){
       this.files = undefined;
       return;
    }

    // continue if the uploaded file actually contains some information
    reader.readAsDataURL(img); // read file as data url
    this.files = img;

    reader.onload = (event: any) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
      //   console.log(event);
      this.url = event.target.result;
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can build your model this way:

```
this.vehicle = {
    registration_number: this.createForm.value.registration_number,
    vehicle_image: this.files == undefined 
         ? null
         : (this.files, this.files.name),
};
```

Let me know in the comments if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: It complain that files.name cannot be found. and when I added vehicle_image: this.createForm.value.vehicle_image,   insted  no image is stored

Comment: According to the code that I've provided, the `files` variable will have the value of `undefined` if user uploads an invalid image or something causes the uploaded file to have 0 bytes. In this case, if `files` is undefined, you won't be able to access file's name, because simply it's undefined :) Before using `this.files` in your code, make sure it's not undefined